# Why do I get NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat when rastering SVG to PNG with ImageMagick in PHP?

Tags: svg, imagemagick

I'm trying to convert svg image to png with the following code:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($_POST['svgcode']);
$image->setImageFormat("png24");
$image->resizeImage(600, 600, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

But there is an error in the second line:

```
NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/361
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you got imagick installed with svg support?

Comment: Yes, I suppose because of this: [from php info](http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6703/181340987.0/0_d5dda_69bea3d4_orig)

Comment: you may need to download and reinstall imagick with delegates http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post helped me a lot: https://web.archive.org/web/20140210005135/https://www.elxsy.com/2009/07/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-and-using-with-php-imagick/

To be exact this piece:

> This is the important part, I spent good half an hour trying to make it work.. grrrr.. You need to restart your PC to libraries take effect.

Never did this for installing php extensions.

Answer (score 5):

First line of your svg must be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>`

```
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$svg;
```

Do it and you will be enjoying :-)

Comment: Awais, thank you for commenting. I've just restarted my PC and the problem was solved.