# Imagemagick memory exception

Tags: php, drupal, imagemagick

i have the below script, it runs fine up until $image->readImageBlob($svg) at which point it throws:

ImagickException: Memory allocation failed `/tmp/magick-XXRrIUil' @ svg.c/ReadSVGImage/2825 in Imagick->readimageblob() (line 73 of ***).

```
<?php
    //if its not a png, we're a registered user, they have confirmed an overwrite, so just replace it.
        $file = file_save_data($image['contents'], $_GET['dir'].'/'.$_GET['name'], FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
        cg_utils_watch("file object on svg save", "", $file); //logging function 1

        $fhandle = fopen($file->uri, 'r');
        $result = fread($fhandle, filesize($file->uri));
        //apparently needed for image magic, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661811/convert-svg-to-png-with-imagemagick-in-php top answer
        $svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$result;
        cg_utils_watch("fread result","",$svg); // logging function 2
        fclose($fhandle);

        //make png of svg for display on user end. svg is used for editing and pdf generation on order.
        $image = new Imagick();
        $image->readImageBlob($svg);
        cg_utils_watch("png from svg", "", $image); //logging function 3
        $image->setImageFormat("png24");
?>
```

essentially i am looking to take an svg file and convert it to png. but i cant seem to get around this memory issue.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT::

Just running a simple test with the application, making a thumbnail of an image. The script sucessfully completes, and then throws a seg fault.

script:

```
<?php
$im = new imagick( 'a.jpg' );
// resize by 200 width and keep the ratio
$im->thumbnailImage( 200, 0);
// write to disk
$im->writeImage( 'a_thumbnail.jpg' );
?>
```

result is a working file called a_thumbnain.jpg in the root and an output of "segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: pretty sure i didnt with this, its still sitting waiting to be done. just not top of my list at the moment

Comment: Maybe you can try conversion via shell execution like this?
exec("convert  $svg $image");
Have you tried that?